# Flowchart a C Function

Tags: c

THIS IS A HOMEWORK ASSIGNMENT. I am asking about creating a logic flowchart. I have been struggling to write this code, so if someone would verify my attempt to solve it, that would be great.

Problem:

Insert string1 into string2 at position 'pos'. The characters following 'pos' will be moved to fall after the characters from string2. NO characters will be deleted.

Plan to solve:

Count the length of S1 and S2.

Copy character from s1[pos] to s1[pos+LengthOfS2]
(Is there a certain way to terminate this array?)

Insert the contents... s1[last empty spot(-1 each time)] =s2[LengthofS2(minus one each time]

Terminate the array

Does this make any sort of sense? :/

EDIT: I cannot use string.h functions such as strcopy or memory manipulation.

Comment: You can't use any standard functions? You mean you can't include stdlib.h or string.h?

Comment: String functions, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assume you want to insert string2 below into position f in string1
string1 equals "xxfxx"
string2 equals "yyyyy"

first allocate a large buffer to hold the result.

```
memcpy(string1, buffer, 0, 2);
memcpy(string2, &buffer[2], 0, 5);
memcpy(&string1[2], &buffer[2+5], 0, 3);
```

your task is to replace this hardcoded numbers with dynamic ones that are function of each string length and the position of letter 'f'

I hope this helps also consider using strcpy or wstrcpy instead of memcpy. If the program is MB not Unicode then memcpy is good enough.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to include in the OP that I cannot use any functions such at strcopy. I have to use workarounds to replicate their effect.

Comment: make a function called myCpy(src, dest, startIdx, count)
and use it that is easy :)
do not forget the first two params are pointers and the last two are passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

It is just an idea how you can accomplish it with only arrays. It is up to you what you are going to use. Happy studying!

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(int argc, char ** argv ){

  char s1[] = "WWW";
  char s2[] = "HelloEverybody";

  printf("String S1 is: %s\n", s1);
  printf("String S2 is: %s\n", s2);

  int i, j, pos = 3;
  char comb[17];

  for(i = 0; s2[i] != 0; ++i){
  //printf("Char is: %c\n", s2[i]);

  if ( i != pos ) {
     comb[i] = s2[i];
  } else {
     for (j = 0; s1[j] != 0; ++j){
        comb[i+pos+j] = s2[pos+j];
        //printf("Pos + j is: %c\n", s2[pos+j]);
        comb[pos+j] = s1[j];
     }
     i = 2*pos + j;
     //printf("Pos + j =%i\n", i);
     break;
  }

 }

 int t;
 for (t =i; s2[t-pos] !=0; ++t) {
      comb[t] = s2[t-pos];
  }

 printf("Combined string is %s\n", comb);

 return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

But what does it mean to “insert” and how do you do it?

The key to this is to realize that *insertion* of `string1` in `string2` can be broken down into copying the beginning of `string2` up to `pos`, appending `string1` onto that “half copy”, and then appending the rest of `string2` onto the end of that.

The easy way to do this is to use a buffer to store the result. It must be big enough to store the resulting string, i.e. at least: the sum of the lengths of `string1` and `string2`, plus one for the terminating NUL. If it's too big, that's OK, but it can't be too small.

If you familiarize yourself with the string manipulation functions that are available to you in `<string.h>`, such as `strlen()`, `strncat()`, and `strncpy()`, you shouldn't have much problem.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to write in psuedo-code, this problem appears to be something like:

```
L1 = length of string1
L2 = length of string2
P  = position in string2 where string1 is inserted

perform edit checks to see that P < L2 and L1 > 0 and L2 > 0
// any other checks??

string3 = allocated new storage for a length of L1 + L2;

for (idx = 0 to idx < POS)
   copy char from string2[idx] to string3[idx]

for (idx = POS to idx < POS + L1
   copy char from string1[idx - POS] to string3[idx]


for (idx = POS + L1 to idx < L1 + L2
   copy char from string2[POS - L1] to string3[idx]

print string3 to debug results
```

Not sure if this is the assignment, but modify psuedo-code to correctly reflect the assignment and then write the c code.

Notice, that this psuedo-code is NOT c code, but it can be easily translated into C code.